# Copy whole database from SQL Server to SQL Server using linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, export

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio installed in my system. And using linked server I have connected to a linked server.

Now here I need to copy whole database from linked server to my local SQL Server using linked server itself.

I am using a linked server instead of backup/restore because using linked server I can copy remote database.

Tool used: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Comment: "using linked server I can copy remote database.". There are many methods of copying a remote database and linked server is about the worst one

Answer (score 1):

Backup/restore, the Copy Database Wizard, and Log Shipping are all potentially better choices than linked server copies.

See the following documentation:

- [Back Up and Restore of SQL Server Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases)
- [Use the Copy Database Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard)
- [About Log Shipping (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution to copy database  using linked server at all! but if you are really really forced to do it (and you have try all the other ways) and you have a simple database with not a lot of data,
First You can **generate script** of your database:

**Right-click on your database > Tasks > Generate Scrip > Choose Entire Database > Next**

Advanced options:
Type of data to script: Schema and data
Table\Views Options: Set all to true (except Data Compressions and Full-Text Indexes)
...(and set other options)

Change queries for your linked server using replace "[DatabaseName]."   with "[linkedserver].[databaseName]."

I'm not really fan of this but this might be useful sometimes.

Answer (score -4):

You can use 'select into' construct to load data from tables on a linked server to your local server.
I have just tested it and i works perfect ecpecially if you have few tables to get. Otherwise you will have to create some sort of a cursor to get the list of tables and data from them.

Comment: Using this option *might* allow them to copy the database on a table-by-table basis but would not include any indexes, foreign keys, triggers, views, sps, functions, CLR modules etc, and would also introduce potential strain on the network, generate unnecessary transaction log on the target and create an unregulated, unmaintained copy of the database no-one knows about.  For those reasons, it's a downvote from me, hope you understand : )